# How to handle collision-end in arcade physics

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, phaser-framework

I need to show some icon, when player overlap with game object and hide it when collision with the object ended

i tried this :

```
create() {
    this.physics.add.overlap(player,obj,()=>{
        this.objCollide = true;
    });
}

update() {
    if(this.objCollide){
        this.icon.setAlpha(1);
    }else{
        this.icon.setAlpha(0);
    }
}
```

It works, but when player collide with the object, icon starts flicker, because update function sets alpha 0, but then, after millisecond sets alpha 1. I don't like that flicker effect. So how can i do something like that : this.physics.add.overlapEnd(player,obj, func) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution would be to just to use the `this.physics.overlap` function in the `update` function, and setting there the Alpha.

> ***Watchout:** `this.physics.overlap` not `this.physics.add.overlap`, the first does once a check, the later, adds a eventlistener for overlaps.*

**Small Demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            gravity:{ y: 100 },
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create,
        update
    },
}; 

function update(){

    if(this.physics.overlap(this.box1, this.box2)) {
        this.box2.setAlpha(.5)
    } else {
        this.box2.setAlpha(1)
    }
}

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Overlap')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
    graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    graphics.generateTexture('img', 10, 10);
    
    this.box1 = this.physics.add.image(50, 10, 'img').setDepth(100);
    this.box2 = this.add.rectangle(0, 100, 550, 50, 0xff0000)
      .setOrigin(0);
    
    this.physics.add.existing(this.box2, true);
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```